# Custom theme color in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, color-theme, windows-10-v1511

I'm using **Windows 10 build 10586**. I want to set a custom color for titlebars and start.

I have tried multiple methods described in tutorials but all of them shows the right color in the settings but applies a different color to windows and other sections.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2xFP.png]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Exactly which methods did you employ?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 almost all methods you can find by googling. But I've found a solution by myself and I'm testing it and will post it here as I finish it.